# How to catch the ConnectionRefusedError when using HTTPHandler in Python logging module?

Tags: httphandler, python-3.9, python-logging

Python logging module is not raising exception when target url is not reachable while using http type handler.

### logger.py file

```
import logging
class MyLogger:

    def __init__(self):
        global loggers_dict
        loggers_dict = {}

    def get_me_a_logger(self, _name, _level, _log_file, _addHttpHandler: bool = False, _webServerIP='127.0.0.1', _webServerPort: str = '8000'):
        global loggers_dict
        if loggers_dict.get(_name):
            return loggers_dict.get(_name)
        else:
            logger = logging.getLogger(_name)

            # create a file handler
            LogFileHandler = WatchedFileHandler(filename=_log_file, mode='a')
            if _addHttpHandler:
                httpHandler = HTTPHandler(host=f'{_webServerIP}:{_webServerPort}',
                                          url=f'http://{_webServerIP}:{_webServerPort}/logserver',
                                          method='POST',
                                          secure=False,
                                          credentials=None,
                                          context=None)

            if 'CRITICAL' in _level:
                logger.setLevel(logging.CRITICAL)
                LogFileHandler.setLevel(logging.CRITICAL)
                if _addHttpHandler:
                    httpHandler.setLevel(logging.CRITICAL)
            elif 'ERROR' in _level:
                logger.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
                LogFileHandler.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
                if _addHttpHandler:
                    httpHandler.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
            elif 'WARNING' in _level:
                logger.setLevel(logging.WARNING)
                LogFileHandler.setLevel(logging.WARNING)
                if _addHttpHandler:
                    httpHandler.setLevel(logging.WARNING)
            elif 'INFO' in _level:
                logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
                LogFileHandler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
                if _addHttpHandler:
                    httpHandler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
            elif 'DEBUG' in _level:
                logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
                LogFileHandler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
                if _addHttpHandler:
                    httpHandler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
            # create a logging format
            setLogFormat = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s; %(process)d; %(name)s; %(module)s; %(levelname)s; %(funcName)s; %(lineno)d; %(message)s')
            LogFileHandler.setFormatter(setLogFormat)
            if _addHttpHandler:
                httpHandler.setFormatter(setLogFormat)
            # add the file handler to the logger
            logger.addHandler(LogFileHandler)
            if _addHttpHandler:
                logger.addHandler(httpHandler)
            loggers_dict[_name] = logger
            return logger
```

### main.py file:

```
import logger
localLogger = logging.get_me_a_logger('my_logger_XYZ', logging_level = 'INFO',                            log_file, True, http_logging_ip, http_logging_port)

try: 
    localLogger.info('This is test message')
except Exception:
    print('There is some exception')
else:
    print('all good')
```

Note: Everything goes well when I have a web server active and running i.e. url end point i used while adding HTTPhandler (url=f'http://{_webServerIP}:{_webServerPort}/logserver') is available.

If this is not the case, i get following on console output:

```
--- Logging error ---
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.9/logging/handlers.py", line 1251, in emit
    h.endheaders()
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.9/http/client.py", line 1280, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.9/http/client.py", line 1040, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.9/http/client.py", line 980, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.9/http/client.py", line 946, in connect
    self.sock = self._create_connection(
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.9/socket.py", line 844, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.9/socket.py", line 832, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused
Call stack:
  File "/root/main.py", line 394, in <module>
    if start_logging():
  File "/root/main.py", line 158, in start_logging
    localLogger.info('This is test message')
Message: "'This is test message'"
Arguments: ()
```

I am trying to catch the 'ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused' and unable to do so. If i am able to catch this exception, i can remove the HTTPHandler from my logger and move forward with watchedfilehandler only.

any help?